# Why Underscores in Numeric Literals in Java SE 1.7 Rules are different in Octal and Hexadecimal? Isn't Octal literal violating the rule?

Tags: java, literals

According to [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) underscores cannot be put at the beginning of a number which is just fine. But when it comes to Octal Number we can put underscores at the beginning. Isn't it weird?

```
int x1 = 0x_52;            // Invalid; cannot put underscores at the beginning of a number
int x2 = 0_52;             // OK (octal literal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that:

> Underscores are allowed as separators between digits that denote the integer.

There is a difference in what constitutes the *digits that denote the integer* when it comes to literals with a radix prefix, for hex/binary:

> ... the integer is only denoted by the digits *after* the 0x or 0b characters and before any type suffix. Therefore, **underscores may not appear immediately after 0x or 0b, or after the last digit in the numeral**.

Howerver for *Octal* the rules are different:

> In a decimal or octal literal, *the integer is denoted by all the digits in the literal* before any type suffix. Therefore, underscores may not appear before the first digit or after the last digit in the numeral. **Underscores may appear after the initial 0 in an octal numeral (since 0 is a digit that denotes part of the integer)** and after the initial non-zero digit in a non-zero decimal literal.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1